# When & Why use annotation binding?

Tags: java, kotlin, dependency-injection, binding, annotations

I'm trying to understand the use case of Binding Annotation and why to use them. I've found some examples online like the following that show how to use annotation binding but I'm failing to understand why annotation binding is needed in the first place? And why would we want to provide multiple objects of the same type?

Occasionally, you may want multiple bound instances of the same type. For instance you may want both a FooHttpClient <: HttpClient and a BarHttpClient <: HttpClient.

```
package example.http.clients.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Qualifier
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface FooClient {}

object MyHttpClientsModule extends TwitterModule {
  val fooClientDestination = flag("foo.client.dest", "Foo Client Destination")
  val barClientDestination = flag("bar.client.dest", "Bar Client Destination")

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  @FooClient
  def providesFooHttpClient: HttpClient = {
    val dest = fooClientDestination.get match {
      case Some(value) => value
      case _ => "DEFAULT"
    }

    new HttpClient(dest)
  }

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  @BarClient
  def providesBarHttpClient: HttpClient = {
    val dest = barClientDestination.get match {
      case Some(value) => value
      case _ => "DEFAULT"
    }
    new HttpClient(dest)
  }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why would we want to differentiate between multiple instances of the same type?
2. If 2 classes implement a similar interface but have different implementations, why would we not provide the 2 different implementations as 2 separate objects since they both do the job differently?

EDIT:
If the underlying implementation is different then wouldn't it be easier to just provide 2 separate objects of different types even though those 2 objects implement the same interface?

```
interace A {
  //only one method 
  void foo()
}

class X implements A {

   @override void foo() {
     
   //different implementation then Class Y
   }
}

class Y implements A {

   @override void foo() {
     
   //different implementation then Class X
   }
}
```

**why not provide object X and Y rather then providing objects of type A and then use @Name/Binding annotation?**

Comment: Agreed but for providing different values for type string, we can use @named etc. I'm just trying to understand why would one need 2 different objects be passed with the same parent type and then create annotation binding for it. Eg. class 1 & class 2 both implement interface A, implementations of both classes is different then why provide them with type A?

Comment: Sure, you can use `@Named`, but then you have to keep track of which names you have and haven't used.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you think your application will only need one `String`?  Or one `Set<String>`?  Or `boolean`, for whether or not varying flags are set?
2. Generally, the use case is for swapping in different implementations, especially for tests.  For example, in a test you might want to use a simple local `Set` when in production code you'd actually be sending RPCs to a whole database.

Comment: But if the underlying implementation is different then wouldn't it be easier to just provide 2 separate objects of different types even though those 2 objects implement the same interface?

Comment: No, because you want them to be injected to the same place, without having to change the code that uses them.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me. Could you please link me to an example. I'm a noob failing to understand the concept without a concret example.

Comment: if one wants them to be injects in the same place/method. How would you pick an object annotated with a specific binding annotation without modifying the code?

Comment: You have the same code being injected into, but different modules with different bindings.